# Error Reading from a Pipe

Tags: c, process, pipe

```
void turtle (int gtot)
{
    int msg;
    fcntl(gtot,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
    read(gtot,&msg,4);

    gotoxy(12, 21); printf("The value of buffer for turtle is %d",msg);

    //react to god's message
    xcoor += msg;
    msg = 0;
            sleep(sleep_time);
 }

 void god (int gtot )
 {
        char choice, sign;
        int distance;
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        //choice = getchar();
        gotoxy(1,18);
        printf("Enter the distance which should be moved");
        fflush(stdout);
        gotoxy(50, 14);
        scanf ("%d", &distance);
        int newd = distance;
        //printf ("The distance that is to be moved by %d", distance);

        if (choice == 'h')
        {
            write(gtoh,&distance,4);
        }
        else if (choice == 't')
        {
            write(gtot,&newd,4);
            gotoxy(12,23);
                            printf("I am writing %d as the number", distance); 
                            fflush(stdout);
        }
        //printf("You chose %s", &choice);
        sleep(sleep_time);
    }
    main(){
int gtot[2];
pipe (gtot);
pid_turtle = fork ();
if (pid_turtle == 0)
  {
      close (gtot[1]);
      turtle (gtot[0]);
  }

pid_god = fork ();
if (pid_god == 0)
  {
      close (gtot[0]);
      god (gtot[1]);
  }
   }
```

When I write from the pipe from God function to the Turtle function. I expect it to return nothing when the user gives no input and the numbers when the user gives any. But the printf statement is printing outputs like

```
       The value of buffer for turtle is 0106368
       The value of buffer for turtle is 05291328
```

Which seems to me like the memory address of the number. What is the error that I am making in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several observations about your program:

In function `turtle`:

1. You do not initialize the variable `msg`.
2. You set the `gtot` file descriptor for `O_NONBLOCK`.
3. BUT you do not check the return value of `read`.

This is a significant problem.  `read` is returning immediately and you are printing the uninitialized value of `msg`.

- The way you `fork` and `close` is also contributing.  You have closed `gtot[1]` prior to `fork`-ing the "god" process.  If you choose to use this one-parent of two-child-processes approach, don't `close` the file handles until you are done `fork`-ing.
- Also, it appears that you intended for at least the `turtle` function, and probably the `god` function, to loop.  As written, your turtle function will immediately exit: it has no loop and it performs `read` with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag set.
- But wait, there is more.  When you do call `fcntl` to set `O_NONBLOCK`, what you are doing is also resetting every flag other than `O_NONBLOCK`.   Here is a function taken from [the libc documentation](http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~macewicz/dokumentacja/gnu/libc/libc_8.html) which handles the other flags while setting or resetting the non-blocking flag:

/* Set the O_NONBLOCK flag of desc if value is nonzero,
   or clear the flag if value is 0.
   Return 0 on success, or -1 on error with errno set. */

```
int
set_nonblock_flag (int desc, int value)
{
  int oldflags = fcntl (desc, F_GETFL, 0);
  /* If reading the flags failed, return error indication now. */
  if (oldflags == -1)
    return -1;
  /* Set just the flag we want to set. */
  if (value != 0)
    oldflags |= O_NONBLOCK;
  else
    oldflags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
  /* Store modified flag word in the descriptor. */
  return fcntl (desc, F_SETFL, oldflags);
}
```

There are some other things which could also be contributing to your problem:

- It would be best to replace every occurence of "`4`" with `sizeof(int)` wherever you are calling `read` and `write`.  It is possible that integers are 8 bytes on your machine (64 bit integer?), although pretty unlikely.  In the future, it is more likely that `int` would be 8 bytes, and your code is very fragile in this regard.

There is also something "Strange" about your program that I am observing:

- Why is the decimal output from `printf` being prefixed with a leading `0` (zero)?  That would be an octal representation, but the `printf` specifier is not `"%o"`.  `"%d"` should not show leading zeros unless you use a width-specifier with a leading zero, a la `"%08d"`.  So I don't know what to make about that.

Comment: And thanks again for other pieces of advices that you gave. They really helped my program and ofcourse me. :D

Answer (score 2):

you dont want to call fork twice.
You also dont want to close the unused ends of the pipe:)

Comment: I am supposed to call fork 4 times because of the nature of the programme it is a part of. But, why should I not close the unused ends of the pipe. I thought that is a good practice :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is Linux try using strace to see the exact data being written to the pipes.

If this is Solaris or Mac OS X try dtrace or dtruss.

On BSD I believe the command to view system calls is just truss.

These are *very* useful commands.